# How to change color of svg file in Qt?

Tags: qt

I want to change the red and green parts of the picture to different colors. How can I do that?

I've actually used examples using ChangeSVGColor() and SetAttrRecur() functions, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Show your code which you used. There is no such a standard function as `ChangeSVGColor` or `SetAttrRecur` in Qt that I know of.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsawjrwgoa9h0if/loadsvg.zip?dl=0

Comment: When I run the project in this link, the picture is displayed divided into two windows. How can I change it so that a black background picture appears on one main screen? (You must change the IMAGE_FILE_PATH path in mainwindow.h to suit your environment.)